# Assigning variables to DOM event listeners when iterating

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I'm thinking there's some basic stuff that I'm missing here;

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
  var o = $('#asd'+i);

  o.mouseover(function() {
    console.info(i);
  });
}
```

When hovering over the five different elements, I always get out the last value from iteration; the value `5`. What I want is different values depending of which element I'm hovering, all from `1` to `5`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a closure, as all of the mouseover functions are referencing the same variable whose value is changing:

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    (function(j) {
        $('#asd'+j).mouseover(function() {
            console.info(j);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

By creating a closure, the variable `j` is inside the local scope of the function and will not change when the "outer" `i` changes.

Comment: There was indeed some basic stuff I was missing :-) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This saved my day. And really important to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your function calls in more closures:

Refer to this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3a_A_common_mistake

I think this should work:

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
  var o = $('#asd'+i);
  (function(j){
    o.mouseover(function(){
      console.info(j);
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case `i` is bound inside a closure on each iteration, meaning that all the functions added to the objects points to the *same* variable, and since this variable was incremented on each iteration all functions refer to the last incremented value.

The way to avoid this is by copying the value to a new variable inside the closure

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
     var o = $('#asd'+i);
    (function(newi) {
        o.mouseover(function() {
            console.info(newi);
        });
    }(i);
}
```